Orderby expression for a complex data type while using Azure AI search
I have a payload that looks like follows
{
    "Name": "XXXX",
    "Surname": "",
    "Employers": [
        { "name", "Emp 1", "Salary", 20000 },
        { "name", "Emp 2", "Salary", 21000 },
        { "name", "Emp 3", "Salary", 11000 },
    ]   
}

I am looking to sort the results from based on the salary using orderby but it looks like its not supported. Couldnt find any supporting example. Tried the following
{
   "search": "Somename",
   "select": "Name,Surname"
   "orderby": "Employers/Salary asc" 
}

When i use above it gives me the error

The parent value for a property access of a property 'Salary ' is
not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single
value


The sort criteria must be the path of a sortable field. Since Employers is a Collection(Edm.ComplexType), the field Salary cannot be enabled for sorting because it is directly or indirectly contained in a collection, making it a multi-valued field. Sorting is not allowed on multi-valued fields. For more information, refer to this SO. Alternatively, you can separate the Salary field to enable sorting.

A simple field can be sortable only if it is a single-valued type such as String or Int32.

From this MSDOC

a simple field can be sortable only if it is single-valued (it has a single value in the scope of the parent document). Simple collection fields cannot be sortable, since they are multi-valued. Simple sub-fields of complex collections are also multi-valued, and therefore cannot be sortable.


Change your data to example data below with single-valued only.

private static void UploadDocuments(SearchClient searchClient)
{
    var batch = IndexDocumentsBatch.Create(
        IndexDocumentsAction.Upload(new Employee
        {
            EmployeeId = "1",
            Name = "John",
            Surname = "Doe",
            EmployeeName = "John Doe",
            Salary = 60000
        }),
        IndexDocumentsAction.Upload(new Employee
        {
            EmployeeId = "2",
            Name = "Jane",
            Surname = "Smith",
            EmployeeName = "Jane Smith",
            Salary = 75000
        }),
        IndexDocumentsAction.Upload(new Employee
        {
            EmployeeId = "3",
            Name = "Alice",
            Surname = "Johnson",
            EmployeeName = "Alice Johnson",
            Salary = 50000
        })
    );


The sample c# code below uses  Azure Cognitive Search for indexing and querying employee data Using OrderBy.
It involves creating an index, uploading documents, and running queries on the indexed data.The code reference is taken from MSDOC
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Threading;
using Azure;
using Azure.Search.Documents;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes.Models;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace AzureSearchExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

           
            SearchIndexClient indexClient = CreateSearchIndexClient(configuration);
            string indexName = configuration["SearchIndexName"];

            Console.WriteLine("Deleting index...\n");
            DeleteIndexIfExists(indexName, indexClient);

            Console.WriteLine("Creating index...\n");
            CreateIndex(indexName, indexClient);

        
            SearchClient searchClient = indexClient.GetSearchClient(indexName);

            Console.WriteLine("Uploading documents...\n");
            UploadDocuments(searchClient);

           
            SearchClient searchClientForQueries = CreateSearchClientForQueries(indexName, configuration);

            Console.WriteLine("Running queries...\n");
            RunQueries(searchClientForQueries);

            Console.WriteLine("Complete. Press any key to end application...\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static SearchIndexClient CreateSearchIndexClient(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            string searchServiceEndPoint = configuration["SearchServiceEndPoint"];
            string adminApiKey = configuration["SearchServiceAdminApiKey"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceEndPoint) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(adminApiKey))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Search Service Endpoint or Admin API Key is not set.");
            }

            return new SearchIndexClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), new AzureKeyCredential(adminApiKey));
        }

        private static SearchClient CreateSearchClientForQueries(string indexName, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            string searchServiceEndPoint = configuration["SearchServiceEndPoint"];
            string queryApiKey = configuration["SearchServiceQueryApiKey"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceEndPoint) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryApiKey))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Search Service Endpoint or Query API Key is not set.");
            }

            return new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey));
        }

        private static void DeleteIndexIfExists(string indexName, SearchIndexClient indexClient)
        {
            try
            {
                var index = indexClient.GetIndex(indexName);
                if (index != null)
                {
                    indexClient.DeleteIndex(indexName);
                }
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException e) when (e.Status == 404)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The index doesn't exist. No deletion occurred.");
            }
        }

        private static void CreateIndex(string indexName, SearchIndexClient indexClient)
        {
            var definition = new SearchIndex(indexName)
            {
                Fields =
                {
                    new SimpleField("EmployeeId", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsKey = true, IsFilterable = true },
                    new SearchableField("Name") { IsFilterable = true },
                    new SearchableField("Surname") { IsFilterable = true },
                    new SearchableField("EmployeeName") { IsFilterable = true },
                    new SimpleField("Salary", SearchFieldDataType.Int32) { IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true }
                }
            };
            indexClient.CreateOrUpdateIndex(definition);
        }

        private static void UploadDocuments(SearchClient searchClient)
        {
            var batch = IndexDocumentsBatch.Create(
                IndexDocumentsAction.Upload(new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = "1",
                    Name = "John",
                    Surname = "Doe",
                    EmployeeName = "John Doe",
                    Salary = 60000
                }),
                IndexDocumentsAction.Upload(new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = "2",
                    Name = "Jane",
                    Surname = "Smith",
                    EmployeeName = "Jane Smith",
                    Salary = 75000
                }),
                IndexDocumentsAction.Upload(new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = "3",
                    Name = "Alice",
                    Surname = "Johnson",
                    EmployeeName = "Alice Johnson",
                    Salary = 50000
                })
            );

            try
            {
                IndexDocumentsResult result = searchClient.IndexDocuments(batch);
                Console.WriteLine("Documents uploaded successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to index some of the documents: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for documents to be indexed...\n");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        private static void RunQueries(SearchClient searchClient)
        {
            var options = new SearchOptions
            {
                IncludeTotalCount = true,
                OrderBy = { "Salary desc" } 
            };

            try
            {
                var searchResults = searchClient.Search<Employee>("*", options);

                foreach (var result in searchResults.Value.GetResults())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Employee ID: {result.Document.EmployeeId}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {result.Document.Name}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {result.Document.Surname}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Employee Name: {result.Document.EmployeeName}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Salary: {result.Document.Salary}");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred while querying: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Surname { get; set; }
        public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
}


Output below is by using Order by on Salary for descending order:

WithOut  Using Order by:


Thank you. I cant change the data model now. I gave a simple example of Employee and Employer, but the data model that i am dealing with is quite complex.

as from above reference which I have shared the  field can be sortable only if it is single-valued (it has a single value in the scope of the parent document). Simple collection fields cannot be sortable, since they are multi-valued.
